# SSRS Dynamic Reports for Key Value Pairs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, dynamic-pivot

I need to use SSRS to create many different reports, and I have been trying to find the best way for me to easily create them as need, and for users to navigate them and use them for their needs.

To give you and idea of the two sets of data I am dealing with:

- EDI file from our customer
- Raw data output from hardware configuration

Now the EDI data is fairly consistent, so these columns are static.
The hardware data is usually a massive list of different configuration. I receive them in different flat files formats and using SSIS or other tools I get the data into Key Value Pairs. Now in a report, I use matrix to keep EDI columns static, it matches with the hardware on serial number, and Hardware data pivots.

So the report does not break, and so I don't give the user too much information, it matches up on another table where I specify what keys I want to be columns.

Here is a small example of one of my reports:

[image: Example]

The green columns are EDI, while the orange is the hardware.

My question is, is there a better way for me to be doing this? Some reports can get complicated like needing total for certain hardware (counting hardrive space, ram total etc.) which is difficult to do dynamically.

I have tried creating in reports in this fashion, with these parameters:

[image: Example 2]

This way I can create the Key columns per project and user can select what report they want to run. The default is All Data.

Is there a better way for me to create these reports? SSRS really doesn't seem to play well with dynamic pivots.

Is there a better tool that will handle these reports dynamically, or let users pick and choose what they want to see in a report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't visualise your data but if I understand correctly, you could have a dropdown list showing all the unique values that are in the column you are using in the column group. Set this to be multi-value and then simply have the `WHERE` clause read something like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumnGroupField IN (@myColumnChoiceParameter)
```

This way the user could select whichever columns they would like.

You could extend this by adding another parameter that has some preset groups of columns (I think you might have one of these already if I understand correctly) that would set the default value of the main `@myColumnChoiceParameter` parameter.

If you want something more flexible then you might want to look at Power BI but depending on how you intend to deploy that might not be a simple option.

Comment: Currently, I do not have a drop down for all unique values. I have predfeined reports they can select from, similar to what you said about the preset groups. Adding individual columns for them to select may be a good idea though. Would power BI be more flexibile with dynamic pivots? I know they allow users to make and save custom reports, which seems useful.

Comment: PowerBI is very good for things like that. You just build the model and then the users can quickly throw together a 'report' in a Matris format with very little effort. For simplicity, try the Desktop version first. It's free and if you need, you can send a PBIX file to the user containing all the data just like you would if you sent them an excel file. They would need to open it in PowerBi desktop but it's good for prototyping and user acceptance. We use PowerBi desktop internally and our analysts love it.

Comment: as for the pre-defined reports. I mean that you could adapt your current drop down to populate the 'all columns' drop down with default columns based on the predefined reports. Basically what you have but expose the column list you have in your table. They can then always select more or deselect anything they don't want.

Comment: I think may need to look into Power BI. The people who look at the data need to be able to interact with it, and if BI can allow them to do that and not rely on me to build them, that's they way to go

Answer (score 1):

You cannot dynamically create columns in SSRS but you can control the visibility of the columns.

1) Create a list in table that contains the names of all the columns that yo want to toggle and include a column titled 'All'.

2) Create a parameter that is based on this table and make sure multi-select is turned on.

3) Right click on every column that you want to toggle, select visibility and then create a condition that checks if the user either selected All or selected the column from the parameter list.

4) Train users that by selecting and deselecting from the dropdown they control whats visible.

Comment: What if they're are hundreds of those hardware columns? I can't have them select all individually each time

Comment: You could try having numerous drop downs  each of which default to none) but I really cannot tell you how to handle hundreds of possible columns.